Minor Water Damage after rain storm. Is my window in need of additional caulking between sill and siding?
A bad storm forced some water into the walls of my 135 year old new-to-me house, which damaged a new coat of paint in the kitchen. The damage occurred right under a window. It appears all of the wood trim and plaster is still in decent shape considering its age.
A flower box was also mounted on the exterior of the house, through the siding under the kitchen window. I removed the flower box and found a large gap where the window-sill underside meets the siding.
I repaired the screw holes used to mount the flower box and will not be reinstalling the box out of fear of future issues, but i am wondering, should I also add caulking to the gap between the window-sill under-side and the siding? I have several more windows/flower boxes that I am repeating this repair on and want to do the best I can without breaking the bank or exposing myself to loads of lead paint/asbestos hazards.
Thanks in advance!!
Pics: https://imgur.com/a/vN9WiS5
